# Es + sein + zu + Infinitiv

Tags: word-usage, infinitive

What's the meaning of "es + sein + zu + Infinitiv" in the following sentence?

> Es war ein stetiger Anstieg bei den Verkaufszahlen zu verzeichnen.

And does the following sentence convey the same meaning?

> Es wurde ein stetiger Anstieg bei den Verkaufszahlen verzeichnet.

Comment: Your attempt is containing the same overall meaning. The difference comes with the tenses used: first talkes about something happening in the past and its ongoing there. Second just talks about a single point event. Like "i was there and saw it happening" vs. "well, it happened". For the fitting rules I'm the wrong guy, thus no answer from me.

Comment: One can get rid of the unpersonal "es" here:  *Ein stetiger Anstieg bei den Verkaufszahlen war zu verzeichnen.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[planetmaker](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/50484/planetmaker), [in their answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/67812/15393), correctly points out the existence of the construction *etw. ist zu tun*, meaning "something is to be done", "something has to be done", which also exists in Latin - for instance in the famous quote *Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam* - "Furthermore, I consider that Carthago has to be destroyed".

With verbs like *tun* or *erledigen*, the construction *etw. ist zu + infinite verb* expresses a *necessity*, the fact that something has to be done:

- *Was ist jetzt zu tun?* - "What has to be done now?"
- *Die Hausaufgaben sind zu erledigen* - "The homework has to be done"

However, most often this construction does not express a necessity, but a *possibility* (often negated), the fact that something can be done. These are some examples for this:

- *das ist zu schaffen* - "that can be done"
- *das Spiel ist nicht mehr zu gewinnen* - "the game is not winnable any more"
- *das Raumschiff ist nicht zu betreten* - "the spaceship cannot be entered"
- *das ist mit mir nicht zu machen* - "You cannot count on me doing this"

In constructions with verbs of perception, this construction means that something is perceivable:

- *Vom Balkon ist das Meer zu sehen* - "You can see the sea from the balcony"
- *Die Musik war noch in der Ferne zu hören* - "You could hear the music even in the distance"

And this applies to your example as well:

- *Es war ein stetiger Anstieg bei den Verkaufszahlen zu verzeichnen.* - "One could notice a steady increase of sales numbers."

Answer (score 0):

Die Form des oberen Satzes folgt der Form

> Etwas ist zu tun

und bedeutet soviel wie

> Etwas muss (oder sollte) getan werden

Vermutlich stammt diese Konstruktion aus dem südwestlichen Sprachraum, da es dem französischen 'il faut faîre' von der Konstruktion her exakt folgt - verständlich ist es aber überall.

Deine Alternative Formulierung ist vollkommen korrekt und nach meiner Erfahrung die etwas gebräuchlichere und / oder formalere Formulierung.

Comment: "Etwas ist zu tun" ist nicht die Bedeutung im Beispielsatz der Frage. Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: Na klar. Die Bedeutung des Beispielsatzes ist synonym mit "Es muss ... verzeichnet werden", also analog zu "etwas muss getan (hier verzeichnet) werden". Müssen im Sinne von "es ist offensichtlich beobachtbar / wahrnehmbar"

Comment: "X ist zu sehen" hat nicht die Bedeutung "Man _muss_ X sehen", sondern "X ist sichtbar", also "man _kann_ X sehen". Ich denke, "X ist zu verzeichnen" ist eher analog zu "X ist zu sehen" - die Bedeutung im Beispielsatz ist also eher "Man konnte einen stetigen Anstieg der Verkauszahlen beobachten".